# Counting number of items in nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following array:

```
const foodMenu = [
  {id: 1, name: 'pasta', nutritionalInfo: ['ve', 'veg', 'gf']}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'pizza', nutritionalInfo: ['gf', 'veg']}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'applePie', nutritionalInfo: ['nuts']}
]
```

I want to display a count on my page of how many of each nutritional info there is. For example, it will look like:

Ve: 1
Gluten free: 2,
Veg: 2,
Nuts: 1

I am not sure of the cleanest way of getting all the data from the nested `nutritionalInfo` array and counting it?

I have tried mapping over them to add to a new `nutritionalInfoCount` array but I am getting a too many rerenders warning:

```
  {foodMenu.map((foodMenu) => (
     foodMenu.nutritionalInfo.forEach((nutritionalInfo) => (
        setNutritionalInfoCount([nutritionalInfoCount, nutritionalInfo])
     ))
    ))
  }
```

Can anyone please help with a way to solve this?

Comment: are you using ReactJS?

Comment: you don't need state to compute the counts and display the result. you should not store computed (or derived) state as more state.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII yes

Comment: Is there a way for foodMenu to change (while the component is active) - so basically: is the user able to change foodMenu (for example delete/add menu items)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to iterate through each foodItem and add the nutritionalInfo for each to a frequency counter.
Try the following:

```js
const foodMenu = [
  {id: 1, name: 'pasta', nutritionalInfo: ['ve', 'veg', 'gf']}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'pizza', nutritionalInfo: ['gf', 'veg']}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'applePie', nutritionalInfo: ['nuts']}
]

const nutritionalInfoCount = {};
foodMenu.forEach(({nutritionalInfo}) => {
  nutritionalInfo.forEach(nutrient => {
    if (nutrient in nutritionalInfoCount) {
      nutritionalInfoCount[nutrient] += 1;
    } else {
      nutritionalInfoCount[nutrient] = 1;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.reduce` is often used to do sums / grouping etc on arrays.

eg.

```js
const foodMenu = [
  {id: 1, name: 'pasta', nutritionalInfo: ['ve', 'veg', 'gf']}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'pizza', nutritionalInfo: ['gf', 'veg']}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'applePie', nutritionalInfo: ['nuts']}
];

const tots = foodMenu.reduce((a,v) => 
 (v.nutritionalInfo.forEach(v=>a[v]=(a[v]||0)+1),a)
,{});

console.log(tots);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to build a frequency map. Once you have the frequency map, you can map and join the entries into a formatted string.

```js
const descriptors = {
  ve: 'Vegan',
  veg: 'Vegetarian',
  gf: 'Gluten Free',
  nuts: 'Nuts',
};

const foodMenu = [
  { id: 1, name: 'pasta', nutritionalInfo: ['ve', 'veg', 'gf'] }, 
  { id: 2, name: 'pizza', nutritionalInfo: ['gf', 'veg'] }, 
  { id: 3, name: 'applePie', nutritionalInfo: ['nuts'] },
];

const calcFrequency = (items, subKey) =>
  items.reduce((outer, item) =>
    item[subKey].reduce((inner, key) => {
      inner[key] = (inner[key] ?? 0) + 1;
      return inner;
    }, outer), {});

const printFrequency = (frequency) => {
  console.log(Object.entries(frequency)
    .sort(([k1], [k2]) => descriptors[k1].localeCompare(descriptors[k2]))
    .map(([key, count]) => `${descriptors[key]}: ${count}`)
    .join(', '));
}

printFrequency(calcFrequency(foodMenu, 'nutritionalInfo'));
```

#### Output

> Gluten Free: 2, Nuts: 1, Vegan: 1, Vegetarian: 2

Answer (score 0):

```
 export default function App() {
  const foodMenu = [
    { id: 1, name: "pasta", nutritionalInfo: ["ve", "veg", "gf"] },
    { id: 2, name: "pizza", nutritionalInfo: ["gf", "veg"] },
    { id: 3, name: "applePie", nutritionalInfo: ["nuts"] }
  ];
  const nutrientContent = {};
  foodMenu.forEach((foodMenu) => {
    foodMenu.nutritionalInfo.forEach(
      (nutritionalInfo) =>
        (nutrientContent[nutritionalInfo] =
          nutritionalInfo in nutrientContent
            ? nutrientContent[nutritionalInfo] + 1
            : 1)
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Object.keys(nutrientContent).map(
        (val) => val + ":" + nutrientContent[val] + ", "
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-hellman-i651cr?file=/src/App.js:0-709)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

### Updated Answer

I noticed that OP updated the question and feel that it could be simpler to use one `.reduce()` instead of two `.forEach()`. Here it is:

```js
const nutritionalInfoCount = foodMenu.reduce(
  (infoCount, { nutirtionalInfo }) => {
    let itemInfoCount = { ...infoCount };

    nutirtionalInfo.forEach((nutritionalItem) =>
      itemInfoCount[nutritionalItem] = itemInfoCount[nutritionalItem] !== null
        ? itemInfoCount[nutritionalItem] + 1
        : 1
    )

    return itemInfoCount;
  , {})
```

It is possible to use 2 `.reduce()` but it feels that it'll let the code "unreadable". If you want, you could do something like this:

```js
const nutritionalInfoCount = foodMenu.reduce(
  (infoCount, { nutirtionalInfo }) =>
    nutirtionalInfo.reduce((internalInfoCount, nutritionalItem) => ({
      ...internalInfoCount,
      internalInfoCount[nutritionalItem]: internalInfoCount[nutritionalItem] !== null
        ? internalInfoCount[nutritionalItem] + 1
        : 1,
    }), { ...infoCount } 
  ), {})
```

### Original Answer

There are some options. Some of them are:

- Use `for` loop and make it a function

```js
const countNutritionalInfo = (foodMenu) => {
  let count = 0
  for (let item of foodMenu) {
    count += item.nutritionalInfo.length
  }

  return count
}
```

- Use `.reduce()` (**personally I think this is the better option**)

```js
foodMenu.reduce((count, item) => count + item.nutritionalInfo.length, 0)
```

- Use `.flatMap()`

```js
foodMenu.flatMap((item) => item.nutritionalInfo)
```